# Python failed to parse dates when reading from csv file

Tags: python, pandas

I've been using

```
pd.read_csv('file.csv',parse_dates=['date_time'])
```

to parse dates and then run DateTimeIndex to read year, month, day from date_time variable. When done correctly, 'date_time' should be formatted as datetime64. But something is in the data column that I keep getting 'object' as variable format so I receive ValueError when DateTimeIndex it. My data is too big for me to find out what exactly happened. How should I handle this so I can perhaps change the anomalies to missing and get the data_time variable parsed? Thanks.

Update:

I did what Edchum suggested except pretty manually. Here is my guess why the data is out of sort: one date was supposed to be 2016 instead it shows 2161. does anyone know why python wouldn't parse date time in this case? How can I identify all rows that are similar to this and delete all?

Comment: Add sample data, in case there is something unique about it. Check syntax for parse_dates.

Comment: I tried the method suggested in the thread but got below error:

Comment: OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-255-255 00:00:00

Comment: You can use the binary search approach to find the problematic record (take the 1st/2nd half, see which has problem, then split further).

Comment: I am quite new to python, what is the binary method?

Comment: it doesn't give me error I parse the variable. it only does when I try to DateTimeIndex it.

Comment: Then edit the question to reflect what exactly you do.

Comment: You can parse the csv in chunks and check when it barfs, if you pass `chunksize=n_rows` where `n_rows` is some arbitrary value like 1000 you can then test if each chunk whether the conversion is successful or not and if not print the line that's duff, the other issue here is do you really want duff data? You could just drop those rows

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev, is binary search approach that you mentioned this:

Comment: final['date_time'] = [dateutil.parser.parse(x) for x in final['date_time']]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv.gz', compression='infer',date_parser=True, usecols=([0,1,3]))
print df.head()

#       id            date_time  posa_continent
#    0   0  2015-09-03 17:09:54               3
#    1   1  2015-09-24 17:38:35               3
#    2   2  2015-06-07 15:53:02               3
#    3   3  2015-09-14 14:49:10               3
#    4   4  2015-07-17 09:32:04               3
```

Comment: This is a neat way to load data directly from gz files. it still doesn't quite solve my problem. apology I cited date_time in the question (to stay general) but it is actually srch_ci column (search check in date) that had the issue. I played around with the data more and confirmed that it is that one particular row (row id=312920) causing all the trouble. So I had it deleted and everything went fine. But thanks for the help!!!

Comment: @CWlearner, if it one row edit that row and add back in.

Comment: Yeah, I think you are right. I am going to change its value to missing so it can be treated later on.

Answer (score 1):

This will help you diagnose the problem. Please run this snippet and post the output of `bad_rows`

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
bad rows = []
good_rows = []
for row, date in enumerate(df['date_time']):
    try:
        good_rows.append((row,dateutil.parser.parse(date)))
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
        bad_rows.append((row,date))
```

Comment: I ran the code but bad_rows seems to capture all the rows vs. good_rows captures none..

Comment: edited. Please give at least a few examples of the `date` that could not be parsed and the corresponding `Exception`

Comment: @michael_j_ward, thanks for following up. I ran it again but got error again. It says "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file"

Comment: @Merlin it is the test file from kaggle expedia contest. here is the link to data: https://www.kaggle.com/c/expedia-hotel-recommendations/data

Comment: I will also try to add a few lines to show as example